# Trouble with OO Design

Tags: oop

I am not sure if this is the place to ask this type of question so please close this question if it is irrelevant.

I am learning about OO design and am having some issues creating a good design for a simple robot system. Here is the gist of it:

A driver operates a robot object. `Robot` is an interface which `BasicRobot` and `HandicapRobot` implement.

Here is the issue: `BasicRobot` has all of the code inside and `HandicapRobot` only differs by two variables. That is, `BasicRobot` has sensors in all directions whereas `HandicapRobot` only has left and forward sensor. Since they are so similar, I made `HandicapRobot` inherit from `BasicRobot`.

However, in some situations, I can only use `BasicRobot` and using `HandicapRobot` would not be appropriate. This violates a substitution rule since a subclass can be used whenever a parent class is expected.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue in an elegant way. Should I get rid of `HandicapRobot` and simply create sensor modifiers for `BasicRobot`?

Comment: To clarify the semantics, is the handicap robot just a regular robot but considered "broken"? If so, I'm not sure that it makes sense to be it's own class, but instead would have some entropy built in to act like a broken version of a basic robot.

Comment: @trnelson It would be considered a lesser version of BasicRobot. It has fewer capabilities.

Comment: What do you mean, "In some situations" you can only use `Basic robot `.  And if the two robots only differ because of variable values, that sounds like they would be instances of the same class rather than different classes

Comment: Make them both inherit from AbstractRobot

Comment: I have to ask, what methods are stopping `HandicapRobot` from deriving from `BasicRobot`?

Comment: @DanielT. I am using robots to analyze maze algorithm effiency. There are some maze algorithms where I can only use BasicRobot and there are other maze algorithms where I can only use HandicapRobot.

Answer (score 2):

A BasicRobot can be used wherever a `HandicapRobot` can be used, but a `HandicapRobot` cannot be used wherever a `BasicRobot` can be used. That implies that `HandicapRobot` should be the base class.

That said, there may be other problems with your hierarchy. If the two variables that are different are bools, then it is likely that you need to break out some code from your base class and put it in your derived class.

Comment: Hi, thanks I thought about this and I ended up using an AbstractRobot that partially implements the Robot interface. Then I had BasicRobot and HandicapRobot extend AbstractRobot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an application of decorator design pattern. You have to create an interface:
IRobot then have two classes implementing this interface BasicRobot and HandicapedRobot. HandicapedRobot will contain an instance of a BasicRobot through the IRobot.

```
interface IRobot{}

class BasicRobot : implements IRobot{}

class HandicapedRobot : implements IRobot{
 IRobot m_internal;
 SomeType m_additionalData;
}
```